# Get unique css selector from WebElement

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, kotlin

is it possible to get a css selector of an WebElement?

eg

```
var optionSelectors = mutableListOf<String>()
val options = selectWebElement?.findElements(By.cssSelector("option")).orEmpty()
for(option in options){
   var optionSelector = option.getSelector()
   optionSelectors.add(optionSelector)
}
return toJson(optionSelectors)
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can always use [Reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javareflection-1536171.html) to get [foundBy](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.141.59/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.java#L58) property value like:

```
Field field = element.getClass().getDeclaredField("foundBy");
field.setAccessible(true);
String foundBy = field.get(element).toString();
```

[image]

However the nature of your question is a little bit weird, given you found the element already you should know its selector, shouldn't you? If you want to interact with the [Select](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) option values you can go for the relevant [Select](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) class which has [getOptions() function](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html#getOptions--).

Also consider going for [Page Object Model design pattern](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model), it is one of best practices to keep your test logic separate from UI layer

Comment: Thank you. It's just an example. I got a bit more complicated case ;)